# Shock-wave noise when I turn the volume high to watch films or listen to music?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have a Lenovo Y410P, a notebook.

If I use a low volume to watch film or listen to music, everything is finem but I get a shock-wave noise like "lilililili" if I turn the volume up high.

I've been using headphones to avoid the problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you get feedback from the microphone ? Try to mute the mic in alsa-mixer or an other mixer-program.

Comment: Ok,i will have a try when i back home,thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I tried,but it can't solve my problem. The mic in alsamixer is muted defaultly.I can lower the master, pcm to get the sound normal, but the volume is lowed too, so i think it is pointless.